# How to view changes made to files on a certain revision in Subversion

Tags: svn

I am looking for a Subversion command which does the equivalent of

```
git show <commit-number>
```

Comment: Does svn cat -r work for you?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

With this command you will see all changes in the repository `path/to/repo` that were committed in revision `<revision>`:

```
svn diff -c <revision> path/to/repo
```

The `-c` indicates that you would like to look at a *changeset*, but there are many other ways you can look at diffs and changesets. For example, if you would like to know which files were changed (but not how), you can issue

```
svn log -v -r <revision>
```

Or, if you would like to show at the changes between two revisions (and not just for one commit):

```
svn diff -r <revA>:<revB> path/to/repo
```

Comment: Note that `path/to/repo` is not required if you have a working copy, which is the normal case (and implied by `git show`). Note also that `git show` compares against the local repo and not the remote, if there is one.

Answer (score 20):

The equivalent command in svn is:

`svn log --diff -r revision`

Answer (score 9):

Call this in the project:

```
svn diff -r REVNO:HEAD --summarize
```

`REVNO` is the start revision number and `HEAD` is the end revision number. If HEAD is equal to the last revision number, it can skip it.

The command returns a list with all files that are changed/added/deleted in this revision period.

The command can be called with the URL revision parameter to check changes like this:

```
svn diff -r REVNO:HEAD --summarize SVN_URL
```